# EPERM mkdir error with gulp.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, build-automation

I'm trying to copy all vendor scripts to build directory, ran cmder as administrator, yet it fails . Please help me out getiing this issue resolved. Thanks in advance.

```
gulp
[17:54:26] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\crossover\gulpfile.js
[17:54:26] Starting 'default'...
[17:54:26] Starting 'build-all'...
[17:54:26] Starting 'clean'...
[17:54:26] Finished 'clean' after 5.49 ms
[17:54:26] Starting 'copy-assets'...
[17:54:26] Starting 'copy-app-js'...
[17:54:26] Starting 'copy-vendor-js'...
[17:54:26] 'copy-vendor-js' errored after 14 ms
[17:54:26] Error: EPERM, mkdir 'C:\Users\desapm\Desktop\crossover\build\vendor'
    at Error (native)
```

The Following is the copy-vendor-js in  gulpfile.jsgulp.task('copy-vendor-js',

```
 gulp.task('copy-vendor-js', function() {
      //Copy all Vendor Scripts to Build Folder
    return gulp.src('./vendor/**/*.*')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/vendor'));
  });
```